# Опрос нескольких устройств по одной шине i2c в linux. ( C/C++)

Tags: c++, linux, c

Есть задача с опросом акселерометра через драйвер Linux. Примеры в интернете есть. [Вот один.](http://blablacode.ru/linux/581)

Обычно это несколько вызовов (пишу без обработок ошибок):

```
const char * devName = "/dev/i2c-1";
int file = open(devName, O_RDWR);
ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, DEV_ADDRESS) // настройка адреса устройства
//Далее уже команды read() или write()
```

В моем случае приходится постоянно вызывать `ioctl` перед командой чтения/записи, чтобы переключить адрес слейва.

Подскажите есть ли какой-то более экономный по запросам вариант?

Comment: открыть файл несколько раз не помогает?

Comment: вам автор статьи из ссылки, как бы намекает, что для нормальной работы надо писать свой драйвер

Comment: У вас драйвер в user space. Ядерные драйверы располагаются а каталоге *drivers/iio/accel*. Соответственно и ABI там совсем другой, специально разработанный для сенсоров.